# Setup Motorola Moto G 2nd gen without sim card

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, factory-reset, sim-card, motorola-moto-g2

Can I reset and resetup my Motorola Moto G 2nd gen [XT1068] smoothly without having a sim card inserted? I don't want the setup system to want my sim card because every setup it auto enables the expensive mobile data with it in.

The moto g runs Android L 5.0.2 and is carrier unlocked.

Comment: Yes, you can do that there's nothing much to worry about it! You can reset your device without inserting SIM card !!

Comment: no problem at all, I guess now you can mark it as answered ! I guess ;)